# Trouble understanding a part of an algorithm

Tags: c++14

The problem is to find special strings

A string is said to be a special string if either of two conditions is met:

- All of the characters are the same, e.g. aaa.
- All characters except the middle one are the same, e.g. aadaa.

This is the code I got and I understand the two cases.

1. Case 1: All Palindromic substrings have the same character
2. Case 2:Count all odd length Special Palindromic substrings with the
   the middle character is different.

What I cannot understand is why I have to delete n from the result, I don't see where I am adding the extra 'n' in the algorithm.

```
int CountSpecialPalindrome(string str)
{
    int n = str.length();
    int result = 0;
    
    int sameChar[n] = { 0 };
 
    int i = 0;
 
    // traverse string character from left to right
    while (i < n) {
 
        // store same character count
        int sameCharCount = 1;
 
        int j = i + 1;
 
        // count smiler character
        while (str[i] == str[j] && j < n)
            sameCharCount++, j++;
 
        // Case : 1
        // so total number of substring that we can
        // generate are : K *( K + 1 ) / 2
        // here K is sameCharCount
        result += (sameCharCount * (sameCharCount + 1) / 2);
 
        // store current same char count in sameChar[]
        // array
        sameChar[i] = sameCharCount;
 
        // increment i
        i = j;
    }
 
    // Case 2: Count all odd length Special Palindromic
    // substring
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        // if current character is equal to previous
        // one then we assign Previous same character
        // count to current one
        if (str[j] == str[j - 1])
            sameChar[j] = sameChar[j - 1];
 
        // case 2: odd length
        if (j > 0 && j < (n - 1) &&
            (str[j - 1] == str[j + 1] &&
             str[j] != str[j - 1]))
            result += min(sameChar[j - 1],
                          sameChar[j + 1]);
    }
 
    // subtract all single length substring
    return result - n;
}
 
// driver program to test above fun
int main()
{
    string str = "abccba";
    cout << CountSpecialPalindrome(str) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: variable-legth-array (VLA) is not part of the C++ standard, which makes `int sameChar[n]` depend on your compiler's extension. This is not likely a cause for you trouble, but still it is preferable to use vector in this case instead.

Comment: Subtracting `n` appears to be incorrect. The program as written produces a wrong answer - off by exactly `n`, far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get the answer without subtracting n and it seems to pass all test cases but this subtracting n seems to be an accepted solution by many.
Most Probably the place from where I referred the solution had committed a mistake.
I thought I was missing something but it doesn't seem like it now.